# Return code of successful or failed write.table in R

Tags: r, csv

**Question:** Is there a way to return the results of a successful or failed `write.table` call? This is what I tried:

```
> x <- write.table(mydata, file="AllDat.csv", sep=",", row.names = FALSE, col.names=TRUE, append=FALSE

Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message: In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open file 'AllDat.csv': Permission denied

> x
NULL
```

The variable x remains NULL even for a successful `write.table`.

Comment: `x` will always be `NULL`.  The result is in the assigned file.  Functions must return a value.  `NULL` is that value.

Comment: What are you trying to assign here? You could test if it worked with `read.table()`

Comment: `?tryCatch` maybe?

Comment: If an error was raised it was unsuccessful, otherwise it was successful? Unlike, e.g. [fwrite in C](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/), R's `write.xxx` functions do have return codes.

Comment: All good answers - I'm learning so much about R so fast my head is spinning!   

@nrussell - Ok, thanks (guessing you meant "do `not` have return codes"). My script writes the table then moves processed files to another directory. I don't want to move the files unless the table was written. Perhaps I can use read.table and compare the number of rows across tables.

Comment: `Return code`, thanks nrussell, that is the terminology I was looking for. Revised original question to reflect correct terminology.

Comment: Use try() and check whether it errors.

Comment: @EKrantz yes sorry; do not have return codes